# Is it possible to merge two or more shape keys together?

Tags: rigging, shape-keys

I want to create a facial rig using shape keys since it will allow for more precision and would be far easier to make than an actual facial rig (with bones). I have yet to plan it out, but I know that I want to be as convenient to use as possible, so I want the mouth to be able to move into *almost* any expression with as few bones as possible. I've attached a couple examples of what I intend to do:
[image]
[image]

I want it to work as though there is an imaginary plane on the surface of both sides of the model's mouth, with a bone to drive the shape keys on both sides. Where ever I move that bone, the two (or more) shape keys will work independently in a sense, but ultimately would give a result as though the two are merged.[image]

I know there is definitely some way to do this without struggling over good topology and, worse, weight painting. If shape keys aren't the answer, then I am more than open to other suggestions (other than good topology, obviously haha).
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What you're describing is how shapekeys work normally.  Are you running into problems somewhere?

Comment: Not exactly- It's a little hard to explain. What I'm trying to do somehow merge two so that I could move the bone anywhere in the "plane" on the mesh. Kind of like an actual face rig, as I want to give the driving bone as much freedom as possible. A shape key has a start and end point, and I was hoping to combine that with another start and endpoint to create said plane (sorry if this is confusing idk how to explain).

Comment: You can drive one shapekey from a bone's X position and a different shapekey from its Y position.  (You can also drive from Z position, XYZ(W) rotation, XYZ scale, etc.)

Comment: that's kind of what I meant actually, but I want them to both move at the same time (for efficiency). That's what I meant by combining them. If it seriously isn't possible that way, the two separate drivers is also an option

Comment: They'll move at the same time, when you move the bone freely in both X and Y axes simultaneously, as you would with a 'g' grab operation.  It's two drivers, but you control both drivers with one operation.

Comment: oh I get it! I'll try that and see if it works out =) ty!